# Is there a mercurial equivalent to gits no-fast-forward merge?

Tags: git, mercurial, merge

What is the mercurial equivalent to gits no-fast-forward merge (in case a fast forward would be possible)?

*Edit*

Assume you have a branch/bookmark at your head/tip of master/default:

```
 o feature
 |
 o
 |
 o master/default
 |
 ...
```

A simple fast forward merge would result in:

```
 o feature/master/default
 |
 o
 |
 o
 |
 ...
```

A no-fast-forward merge would look like:

```
 o merge commit - feature/master/default
 | \
 |  o     
 |  |
 |  o
 | /
 o
 |
 ...
```

Comment: "Update"? Isn't that what fast forward merge is? It just does an update? Of course, Mercurial will not detect this but I don't think it'll try to perform a merge either.

Comment: He was asking for a no fast-forward alternative, not a fast-forward alternative. :)

Comment: If you cannot locate any, would a dummy commit in master before merging produce what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you committed your feature branch.

If the feature was developed on a named branch, then you can get the equivalent of a no fast-forward merge.  In fact, named branches cannot be merged any other way.

```
hg update default
hg branch feature-1
...work...
hg commit -m "implemented feature on named branch"
hg update default
hg merge feature-1
hg commit -m "merged feature-1 to default"
```

This will result in a graph like this:

```
o   merged feature-1 to default
|\
| o feature-1: implemented feature on named branch
|/
o
|
```

This only works with named branches (i.e. branches created using the [`hg branch`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/branch) command).  It does not work for anonymous branches or bookmarks.

You may also be interested in [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/33319/focus=33328) *(dead-link)* on the Mercurial mail list that discusses the issue.

Comment: That would be an idea for people who really like the 'punctuation' of a merge changeset for merging a feature. You have a named branch called 'newfeature' and then several bookmarks within that branch.

Comment: By far the best part of this answer is the last line.

Comment: You can do an Oedipus merge in Mercurial with anonymous heads using the 'debugsetparents' command. See: http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-04-23-debug-command-tricks/#3-simulate-gits-no-ff-merges-with-anonymous-heads.  I think debug commands are not given the compatibility guarantees of the rest of Mercurial, though.